# I want recover breakpoints which was deleted accidently. (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

I accidently delete all my breakpoints and I want to know how to restore them back. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no way, if you don't have a complete backup of your workspace directory.

To avoid this the next time, these are your alternatives:

- Regularly export the breakpoints using File -> Export -> Run/Debug -> Breakpoints.
- Use the [Mylyn provisioning plugin](https://github.com/sschmidt/edu.tum.cs.mylyn.provisioning), which automatically stores your breakpoints in task contexts, when using Mylyn.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the application by killing the process.
It worked in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Restart the application by killing the process. It worked in IntelliJ too